# Модальное окно remodal при закрытии возвращает в начало страницы

Tags: jquery, плагин, href

Возникла проблема при использовании плагина **remodal**.
При закрытии страница прикручивается в самое начало, а нужно чтоб оставалась на месте, откуда было вызвано окно.
Помогите, пожалуйста, в решении данной проблемы.

```js
Remodal.prototype.buildDOM = function () {
        this.body = $(document.body);
        this.bg = $("." + pluginName + "-bg");
        this.modalClose = $("<a href='javascript:void(0);'>").addClass(pluginName + "-close");
        this.overlay = $("<div>").addClass(pluginName + "-overlay");
        if (!this.modal.hasClass(pluginName)) {
            this.modal.addClass(pluginName);
        }
```

Comment: Вангую знак `#` в атрибуте `href`.

Comment: Я заменял # на javascript:void(null); - это ничего не изменило

Comment: Так добавьте свой код в вопрос, иначе только и остаётся, что угадывать.

Comment: Я редактировал - этот учаток кода :
Remodal.prototype.buildDOM = function () {
        this.body = $(document.body);
        this.bg = $("." + pluginName + "-bg");
        this.modalClose = $("<a href='javascript:void(0);'>").addClass(pluginName + "-close");
        this.overlay = $("<div>").addClass(pluginName + "-overlay");
        if (!this.modal.hasClass(pluginName)) {
            this.modal.addClass(pluginName);
        }

Comment: Какую версию remodal используете?

Comment: версия remodal v0.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Беглое чтение github страницы проекта показало, что баг скролинга присутствовал в **Remodal** до версии **0.1.3**. 12 января 2017 выпущена уже версия **1.1.1**.

Скачайте актуальную версию с [официальной Github-страницы проекта](https://github.com/vodkabears/Remodal/releases) и всё будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало!!